# Can I call a computed in the props of a child component in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-props

I have a child component and a father component. in the child component, i have a boolean props with a false default value. I call the component child in the parent component and when i set my child component by computed function which returns a boolean value, i got an error.
child component

```
<template>
  <div v-if="fruitDisplay">
    <span >{{ fruitName }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "childComponent",
  props: {
    fruitDisplay: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      fruitName: 'fruit selected !!!!'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

parent component

```
<template>
  <div id="selector">
    <div v-model="selected" v-for="(item, key) in fruitList" :value="key">
       <child-component :fruitDisplay='getCoconut(item)'></child-component>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
  
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "ParentComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: '',
        fruitList: {
          "fruit1": "Apple",
          "fruit2": "Banana",
          "fruit3": "Coconut"
        }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getCoconut(item) {
      return item === 'Coconut'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I got this error : TypeError: _vm.getCoconut is not a function in the console of my browser and my page doesn 't display. this is the problem :

```
<child-component :fruitDisplay='getCoconut(item)'></child-component>
```

How can i resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve, but I'll try to help. You seem to want to create a selector that will show you **'Fruit selected'** when `Coconut` is selected.

You can't pass parameters to computed properties. But you could use a method that takes the currently selected fruit and then returns true or false.

You might want to create a custom selector, but it lacks more details about your question. That's why I used the typical selector here.

```html
<div>Selected: {{ selected }}</div>

<select v-model="selected">
  <option disabled>Please select one</option>
  <option v-for="(item, key) in fruitList" :key="key" :value="item">
    {{ item }}
  </option>
</select>

<FruitSelector :fruitdisplay="getCoconut()" />
```

And your method:

```js
getCoconut() {
  return this.selected === 'Coconut'
}
```